# Showing <n> =nZ is a prime ideal of Z IFF n is a prime

Tags: ring-theory

> Question:
>
> If n is an integer greater than 1, show that $\left \langle n \right \rangle=n\mathbb{Z}$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ IFF n is a prime.

I have a bit of problem proving the only if condition is true.

> Attempt:

Suppose $\left \langle n \right \rangle$ is a prime ideal of R.

Then $a.b \in \left \langle n \right \rangle$. It is thus true that $a \in \left \langle n \right \rangle \text{or} b \in \left \langle n \right \rangle$

Any hints is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suppose $\langle n \rangle$ is a prime ideal of $Z$. Assume by contradiction that $n$ is not prime. Then $n = ab$ for some non-identity elements $a,b \in Z$. Therefore, $ab \in \langle n \rangle$, yet $a \notin \langle n \rangle$ and $b \notin \langle n \rangle$.

Comment: Also suppose $n$ is prime then for $a,b\in Z$ and $ab \in (n)$ implies $ab=kn$ for an integer $k$. Hence $n$ either divides $a$ or $b$ so either $a\in (n)$ or $b\in(n)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the following useful lemma: $I$ is a prime ideal iff $R/I$ is an integral domain.

So if $(n)$ is a prime ideal iff $Z/nZ$ is an integral domain iff $n$ is a prime.

Comment: Would you be kind to provide a proof for n is a prime ideal IFF z/nz? I see no such theorem in my notebook and certainly not in Gallian.

Comment: @Mathematicing Surely such a theorem is in Gallian (see prime ideals in a ring), and also here at this site.

Comment: This is not entirely correct, since $n=0$ is not prime, but $(0)$ is a prime ideal in $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde it is correct if $n \geq 2$